# django sign up form not storing the username

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a sign up form that does not store the username properly, other fields are stored successfully. Shouldn't it save the username because it is in the fields ? I saw that I cannot login and this is because the row in the table does not have the username.

views.py

```
class SignUpFormView(FormView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'users/authentication/login/signup.html'

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            # some logic here
            user.save()
            messages.success(
                request, "Great! You are able to login now.")
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, form.errors)
            return redirect('login')
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            TbUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except TbUser.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = TbUser

class SignUpForm(CustomUserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    customer_id = forms.CharField(label="Customer ID")

    def clean_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if TbUser.objects.filter(username=data).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Username already exists. Pick another one")

    
    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        password1 = cd.get("password1")
        password2 = cd.get("password2")
        if password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords did not match")

        return cd

    class Meta:
        model = TbUser
        fields = ['username', 'email',  'real_name', 'customer_id',
                  'password1', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clean_username` method of `SignUpForm` does not return anything. You need to return cleaned data for it. So add `return data` to the bottom of this method.